# How to reverse engineer Electron V8 Snapshot Data Blobs?

Tags: disassembly, websites

Electron apps nowadays seem to have a `snapshot_blob.bin` and a `v8_context_snapshot.bin`. I am having a hard time trying to find specification of this file type. It doesn't match with `.wasm`. Files may be platform / CPU architecture specific binaries (and may vary depending on the platform) but I am not sure. They have no typical entry point like a normal PE.

Any advice on reverse engineering these snapshot data blob binary files would be appreciated! I am actually looking for a tool like x64dbg or IDA Pro but also thinking of making a similar debugger by myself if there isn't any available. However, the file specs are needed first. Thanks.

Comment: a google search says [src/snapshot/snapshot.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/master/src/snapshot/snapshot.cc) in google v8 git code base describes the format a cursory glance on vscode snapshot_blob.bin on hxd shows 7.8.279.23-electron.0 in my m/c at offset 10 so have you been there ? doesn't it help ?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't help at all. I have even tried to decode the opcodes manually by following the opcodes inside V8 repository. However, I believe that they don't match since the snapshot is Electron specific. It even has Electron version number written in it if you look into it with i.e. a hex editor. So V8 source alone does not help. We need more information.

Comment: There has been some develop of Ghidra plugin that can aid in that direction. See: https://github.com/PositiveTechnologies/ghidra_nodejs Only problem is that solution work for .JSC, and the snapshot is somehow different format...